# Make a p tag into an input field by pressing on a random card

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to JS, HTML and CSS. So far I created a button which creates random cards. On the card is a `p` tag "title". When you click on the card you will see two input fields and a save- and a delete button.

1. I need help with the design. I tried my best but i cant make this two buttons and the two input fields look good. Can you help me on that.
2. When I click on a card I want the `p` tag title goes into one of the input fields. When I click on the `input` field the `p` tag should disappear again.
3. And what I want to make last is that only one card can be in edit mode.

This is my Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button.plus").on("click", function() {
        var newCard = $('#cardPrototype').clone(true);
        $(newCard).css('display', 'block').removeAttr('id');
        $('#newCardHolder').append(newCard);
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.card', function() {
        $(this).find('form').show();
        $(this).find('span').remove();

    });

    /*delete button*/
    $('body').on('click', '.card .delete', function() {
        $(this).closest('.card').remove();
    });
});
```

```css
.item {
    width: 300px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #BBBBBB;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
button div.item {
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    border-top-left-radius: 55px;
    border: 5px solid white;
    background-color: #666666;
    font-size: 70px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 75px;
    bottom: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
}
.input-feld {
    font-family: TheSans Swisscom;
    margin: 3px;
    width: 260px;
}
.card {
    width: 300px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #BBBBBB;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.delete {
    font-family: 'TheSans Swisscom';
    right: 12px;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.speichern {
    font-family: 'TheSans Swisscom';
    background-color: greenyellow;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.abbrechen {
    font-family: "TheSans Swisscom";
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="plus">
   <div class="item">
      <p>+</p>
   </div>
</button>
<div id="newCardHolder">
</div>
<div id="cardPrototype" class="card" style="display:none;">
   <p  class="delete">x</p>
   <span>Title</span>
   <form name="theform" style="display:none;">
      <input class="input-feld" type="text">
      <br>
      <input class="input-feld " type="text">
      <br>
      <input class="speichern"type="button" onClick="new Person()" value="Speichern">
      <input class="abbrechen"type="button" onClick="new Person()" value="Abbrechen">
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Reto, if you have three different questions, then please ask three different questions. Also, please add a Fiddle.

Comment: We can't really help at all with the first question as that's design related and highly subjective.

Comment: "I want something and this is what I have, and please code it for me".  This is not the way you should ask questions in SOF. You should present the problem with your code, yourself. What is the problem with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try This - May be this might help you

I have changed

- some design changes with CSS
- Input will have a placeholder for the corresponding title in `span` tag
- Only One Item `.class` will be visible in edit mode

```js
$(".plus").on("click", function() {
  var newCard = $('#cardPrototype').clone(true);
  $(newCard).css('display', 'block').removeAttr('id');
  $('#newCardHolder').append(newCard);
});

$('body').on('click', '.card', function() {
  $(this).find('.input-feld').attr("placeholder", $(this).find('span').text());
  $(this).find('span').hide();
  $(this).find('.minimize').show();
  $(this).find('form').show();
});




$('.card').on('click', function() {
  $('.card').find('form').hide();
  $('.card').find('span').show();
  $('.card').find('.minimize').hide();
});


/*delete button*/
$('body').on('click', '.card .delete', function() {
  $(this).closest('.card').remove();
});

/*min button*/
$('body').on('click', '.card .minimize', function() {
  return false;
});
```

```css
.item {
  width: 300px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #BBBBBB;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.item p {
  margin: 0px;
}
div.item {
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border-top-left-radius: 55px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  background-color: #666666;
  font-size: 70px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  bottom: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
}
.input-feld {
  font-family: TheSans Swisscom;
  margin: 5px 3px;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 250px;
}
.card {
  width: 300px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #F4F4f4;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
}
.delete {
  font-family: 'TheSans Swisscom';
  right: 12px;
  top: -10px;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.minimize {
  font-family: 'TheSans Swisscom';
  right: 28px;
  top: -10px;
  color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
.speichern {
  font-family: 'TheSans Swisscom';
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: darkgreen;
  border-color: lightgreen;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.abbrechen {
  font-family: "TheSans Swisscom";
  background-color: orangered;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: white;
  border-color: orangered;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="plus">
    <div class="item">
      <p>+</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="newCardHolder">

  </div>

  <div id="cardPrototype" class="card" style="display:none;">
    <p class="delete" title="delete">&times;</p>
    <p class="minimize" title="minimize">&ndash;</p>
    <span>Title</span>
    <form name="theform" style="display:none;">
      <input class="input-feld" type="text">
      <br>
      <input class="input-feld" type="text">
      <br>
      <input class="speichern" type="button" onClick="new Person()" value="Speichern">
      <input class="abbrechen" type="button" onClick="new Person()" value="Abbrechen">
    </form>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if you could explain your solution to the op, that would be nice :)